# How can i get the id related to specfifc user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get the saloon id related to specific employee. After the login employee can add the service, but my filter query show the error

```
 "Field 'id' expected a number but got <bound method MultiValueDict.get of <QueryDict: {}>>."
```

i don't know how can i get the saloon id

Model.py

```
class SaloonRegister(models.Model):
    saloon_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class SignUp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saloon = models.ForeignKey(SaloonRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()


class Men(models.Model):
    saloon = models.ForeignKey(SaloonRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Service = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.BigIntegerField()
```

View.py

```
class MenView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'men.html'

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       return render(request, self.template_name)

   def post(self, request):
       saloonId = SaloonRegister.objects.filter(signup__user__signup__saloon=self.request.GET.get)
       try:
          men = Men(
               saloon_id=saloonId,
               user_id=request.user,
               Service=self.request.POST.get('service'),
               price=self.request.POST.get('price')
          )
          men.save()
          return redirect('saloonMenu')
       except Exception as e:
          return HttpResponse('failed{}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here

```
    SaloonRegister.objects.filter(signup__user__signup__saloon=self.request.GET.get)
```

as `self.request.GET.get` is a function

```
SignUp.objects.get(user_id =self.request.user.id).saloon_id
```

Will only work if user is in single Saloon if more than one this will fall

Comment: The user who is adding the service man shall choose it from a drop down which will be received as POST key as in your model there is no relation between employee and Salon.

Comment: basically SignUp class is an employee class

Comment: Through saloonRegister it show the error user_id not exist. but when i use  SignUp.object.get(). It works. Thank You bro

Comment: Can u give a favor? can u please tell me how can i show that data related to specific user and saloon

Comment: I fixed the model name,  please accept answer

Comment: i accept the answer  can u please tell me how can i show the data according to user and saloon

Comment: Can you please open a new question with that you want to do?

Comment: i can't ask more question to this week. Just give the idea of query i will write it by myself

Comment: What data are you looking for?

Comment: I fix the query. Can you answer my other question 

       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862590/how-can-upload-word-or-pdf-file-in-django

Comment: What is the data you are looking for?

Comment: i am trying to upload file in Django i share the link of question