# How can upload word or pdf file in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to upload word/pdf file but it's not working. My form submit successfully but file not store in document field. It show empty field and it also not show any error during submit the form, i don't know where is the issue and how can i fix the issue. I add the MEDIA URL in setting and also define the path in urls

View.py

```
 class SaloonRegistration(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'saloonRegistration.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):
       saloon = SaloonRegister(
           saloon_name=self.request.POST.get('saloon_name'),
           owner_name=self.request.POST.get('owner_name'),
           address=self.request.POST.get('address'),
           contact_no=self.request.POST.get('contact_no'),
           document=self.request.POST.get('document')
       )
       saloon.save()
       return redirect('menu')
```

Model.py

```
 class SaloonRegister(models.Model):
     saloon_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()
     document = models.FileField(upload_to='doc/')
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Template

```
 {% extends 'home.html' %}

 {% block content %}
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="saloon_name">Saloon Name
              <input type="text" name="saloon_name" placeholder="Enter Your first name">
          </label>
          <label for="owner_name">Owner Name
              <input type="text" name="owner_name" placeholder="Enter Your last_name">
          </label>
          <label for="address">Address
              <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter email address">
          </label>
          <label for="contact_no">Contact No
              <input type="number" name="contact_no" placeholder="Enter your username">
          </label>
          <label for="document"> upload Doc
              <input type="file" name="document" id="document">
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
 {% endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [file upload in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: i already check the documentation, but i don't know where is the issue

Comment: File uploads come in request.FILES not request.POST

Comment: when i try with    
    document=self.request.POST.get(request.FILES)
it show the error failedunhashable type: 'MultiValueDict'

Comment: document=self.request.FILES.get('document')

Comment: Do u have any idea how can i download this file after upload?

Comment: Check MEDIA in documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484357/how-can-set-the-boolean-value-in-django