# How can set the boolean value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get set the boolean value True when the checkbox is selected but when i select it show the error

```
    failed["“>” value must be either True or False."]
```

and also it show the error when i set the password object have no strip fucntion

Model/py

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

 class Auth_User(AbstractUser):
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View.py

```
class Sign_up(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'Sign-up.html'

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

   def post(self, request):
        try:
           data = self.request.POST.get
           user = Auth_User(
               username=data,
               email=data,
               is_vendor=data
           )
           user.set_password(data('password').strip())
           user.save()
           return render(request, 'home.html')
        except Exception as e:
           return HttpResponse('failed{}'.format(e))
```

Html

```
 <label for="is_vendor">is_vendor
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_vendor">
    </label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using a Form class on this view, your code should look like this:

```py
def post(self, request):
    data = self.request.POST
    user = Auth_User(
        username=data.get('username'),
        email=data.get('email'),
        is_vendor=data.get('is_vender'),
    )
    user.set_password(data.get('password'))
    user.save()
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

If the fields are required, you will need to check the values for each input. Or you use a Form class that does this for you in post. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/ for more info.

Comment: is_vendor get the value " on" i want "True"  when checkbox is selected